# Java: Leap Motion return value from void

Tags: java, methods, void, leap-motion

I'm trying to get my code to scroll up in number between 0 and 255 using the Leap Motion (so prints: 1, then 2, then 3 on cw circles and 3, 2, 1 on acw circles).

The gesture's actions reside in a void onFrame() method.

I need to increment a number each time a circle gesture is detected and output every single number. As it stands, my code does the incrementing in the background and only counts up when I enter the figure (so my counted up figure is displayed in the second prompt). This is bad because the user can't actually see what number they are committing to the threshold prompt.

Please help, I'm pretty new to this and it's slowing my project down!

I've provided stripped down classes to highlight where the issue is.

Listener class:

```
public class ImageJListener extends Listener {

public Robot robot;

public int promptValue;
// potentially look into atomic objects and non atomic objects in case this has a threading issue
public ImageJListener() {
    this.promptValue = 0;
}

public int getPromptValue() {
    return this.promptValue;
}

...

public int onFrame(Controller controller) {
    com.leapmotion.leap.Frame frame = controller.frame();

    for (Gesture gesture : frame.gestures()) {
        if (gesture.type() == Type.TYPE_CIRCLE) {
            CircleGesture circle = new CircleGesture(gesture);
            if (circle.pointable().direction().angleTo(circle.normal()) <= Math.PI / 4) {


                promptValue++;
                return promptValue;


            } else {

                promptValue--;
                return promptValue;

            }

        } else if (gesture.type() == Type.TYPE_KEY_TAP) {
            KeyTapGesture Tap;
            Tap = new KeyTapGesture(gesture);

            try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            } catch (AWTException awt) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Plugin class (that calls the promptValue variable to populate the prompt:

```
    IJ.setRawThreshold(imp, IJ.getNumber("prompt", (listener.getPromptValue())), IJ.getNumber("prompt", (listener.getPromptValue())), null);
```

Many thanks in advance,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value from OnFrame() would not help. OnFrame is called by the Leap Motion code and it wouldn't do anything with the value even if you could provide one. What you need is a function to change the prompt value in place -- if that is even possible. OnFrame could then call that function.

Comment: I was thinking of using the Observable class to pump the updates out - do you reckon that would cut it?

Comment: It seems overkill for calling a single function, but if you anticipate needing to send out more data then just this single integer, then maybe it is worthwhile. I'm not really a Java guy, though, so it is foolish for me to give you Java-style guidance.